# SetInterval function is not working with PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have index.html like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
//alert("abc");
$('#mydiv').load('xyz.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In same folder there is xyz.php file whose code is this:

```
<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>
```

When I uncomment `//alert("abc");` and comment `$('#mydiv').load('xyz.php').fadeIn("slow");`
alert message comes every second but vice versa is not working when I am calling php file and commenting alert message. Why?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: @Ahmad - No, only blank page

Comment: jQuery 1.3? That's ancient!

Comment: Performing an async operation, such as an AJAX call, in a timer loop can lead to unexpected results. You will make an AJAX call EVERY SECOND for no apparent reason. If the response takes longer than one second you could end up queueing up a high number of requests.

Comment: What happens if you visit xyz.php *directly*?

Comment: @Quentin yep, nearly 5 years out of date.

Comment: Simply, your problem is not setInterval, your experiment with `alert` proves that. Its `.load` that is not working.

Comment: @Quentin - its running directly

Comment: I used latest google jquery CDN <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> even then its not working

Comment: it works for me with the same code

Comment: where do you end </head> in your code?

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam - added </head> in my code. typing error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed index.html to index.php and called that by `localhost/firstproject/index.php`. That worked

Answer (score 0):

It´s working for me, but you only can see the content one time, because `.load` function is replacing the old content, change

```
$('#mydiv').load('xyz.php').fadeIn("slow");
```

with this

```
$('#mydiv').append($('<div >').load('xyz.php'));
```

Comment: Or, you know, use `.load()`'s callback.  `$('#mydiv').load('xyz.php', function(){ $(this).fadeIn('slow'); });`