# Not able to run my first program after installing WAMP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, wamp

I installed WAMP. I tested it by localhost\index.php, works. Then I created my first project under www folder named firstproject. I put index.html and xyz.php in it. My xyz.php contents are

```
<?php
  echo "My first PHP script!";
?>
```

My index.html contents are:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
          //alert("abc");
          $('#mydiv').load('xyz.php').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 1000); 
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run index.html, browser is blank. When I try to access xyz.php directly like localhost/firstproject/xyz.php, it works

I had asked similar question yesterday,

[SetInterval function is not working with PHP File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429902/setinterval-function-is-not-working-with-php-file)

everybody says it works on their system. Then why its not working on my system. Is there any configuration I have to do? Please suggest. I am not able to run this simple project.

Comment: why is there a colon `:` after localhost? what is the url you use when calling `index.html`? also we read up on [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) for apache2.

Comment: assuming you're on windows, consider xampp - easy to configure... you need to configure your document root

Comment: @Ryan - I am on windows 7. Console - I have updated jQuery with latest google CDN. gwillie - removed colon. This was a typing mistake.

Comment: Are you calling `http://localhost/firstproject/index.html` ? Are you sure the path to xyz.php in your load() function is correct? Open up FireBug in Firefox or Chrome's Dev COnsole (F12) and see what errors you get. A couple notes: 1) Don't repost questions; 2) always put a doctype in your pages

Comment: @all - renaming index.html with index.php and calling that by localhost/firstproject/index.php is working

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. Check if javascript is enabled in your browser. If not than please enable it and restart the browser.

Comment: renaming index.html with index.php and calling that by localhost/firstproject/index.php is working

Comment: Well. it worked in mine XAMPP using your way.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed index.html to index.php and called that by `localhost/firstproject/index.php`. That worked